# Creating multiple LineStrings for unique values in geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, shapes, geopandas

I have a geodataframe I would like to iterate over and create a LineString for each unique user ID. The dataframe is sorted by timestamp, and userid:

```
               timestamp    userid                     geometry
 30535  2015-02-08 06:18     16301  POINT (942231.63036572517254606.867760913)
 30770  2015-02-09 08:09     16301  POINT (938934.7247729581 7255785.083943168)
 38235  2015-03-13 10:59     16301  POINT (963714.439615038 7227653.687784614)
 42670  2015-01-04 17:32     50136  POINT (944551.6068488198 7253384.182835219)
 42880  2015-03-05 17:07     50136  POINT (963788.4029055665 7228015.063455598)
 42453  2015-05-03 17:32     50136  POINT (963788.4029055665 7228015.063455598)
```

How can I accomplish:

```
LineString([userid 16301 points])
LineString([userid 50136 points])
```

etc?

I am aware of this question [Create LineString for unique values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181883/create-linestring-for-unique-values-in-pandas-dataframe) which does offer a solution, but there must be a simpler way to iterate through the dataframe with iterrows() to create the linestrings?

Comment: Does this do the trick?  `gdf.groupby('userid')['geometry'].apply(lambda x : LineString(list(x)))`

Comment: No, it returns: ValueError: LineStrings must have at least 2 coordinate tuples.

I assume this means there is a userid somewhere with only one associate point?

Comment: That would be my guess

Comment: Maybe you add a condition in the lambda that checks the length